# Why am I getting a System.NullReferenceException error?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an alternative to the code found on this website (https://www.exercisescsharp.com/oop/first-class-method-tostring) where a dynamic list is used rather than an array. However, my code has failed to execute the ToString method and keeps giving me the NullReferenceException.

Below is my code:

```
    public class MainClass
    {
        private static List<Person> person;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = String.Empty;
            while (name != null)
            {
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                person.Add(new Person(name));
            
            }
            foreach (var individual in person)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(individual.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        private string name;

        public Person (string _name)
        {
            name = _name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string ToString()
        {
            return "Hello. My name is" + Name;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `private static List<Person> person = new List<Person>();`

Comment: Voting to close as this is likely not going to help anyone in the future and just a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your `List` instance is not initalized, you have to create it first.

```
private static List<Person> person = new List<Person>();
```